# Saving multiple select form data in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I've got form for some model `A`, which has got few fields:

- tile
- description
- ...
- colors

colors are selected from multiple select and options are `['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']`. User can choose colors as many as he wants. I don't think that making `Color` model and `has_many` relationship is good solution here to store colors data in `model A`. So question is:

How to store multiple data in db for such multiple select forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have limited number of colors, then you can store it as a string: "rby" means that user selected red, blue and yellow. Of course you can use any character to represent any color. In this solution you can easily store about 30-40 colors (what probably is enough). You can also store them as comma separeted words: "red, blue, yellow" and when you fetch it in Rails, just do `@a.colors.split(',')` and you will get array of names of colors.

Although if you want to store it as a string, it requires from you to write some more code in controllers to translate `colors` field to checkboxes and in the other side.

Comment: That is the way I am working now. Kind of csv, :attr_accessor and few extra methods in model. But now I try to understand if there any another solution using serialization or some other exotic stuff. Anyway, thanks for feedback :)